# Renting with the Help to Buy: mortgage guarantee scheme

Tags: mortgage, united-kingdom, first-time-home-buyer

With the Help to Buy: mortgage guarantee scheme, I have heard that you cannot rent out the property under the scheme. Is this true?

Also I have heard that it is possible that if you get a mortgage under the scheme, you can switch mortgage after a number of years to a "real" mortgage, which would allow you to rent out the property. Is this also true?

Answer (score 3):

> With the Help to Buy: mortgage guarantee scheme, I have heard that you cannot rent out the property under the scheme. Is this true?

[Yes you cannot rent out your property to somebody else.](http://www.helptobuy.org.uk/mortgage-guarantee/eligibility)

> Also I have heard that it is possible that if you get a mortgage under the scheme, you can switch mortgage after a number of years to a "real" mortgage, which would allow you to rent out the property. Is this also true?

Yes. I don't understand what do you mean a `real mortgage`. Help to Buy is a mortgage scheme only.

Comment: By "real mortgage" I meant a mortgage where you can rent out. Basically is it possible to switch mortgage from the Help to Buy after you have taken one out?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you want to let a property, you need a buy-to-let mortgage. If you intend to live in a property, you need a residential mortgage. If you go for the latter, and then decide to let the property, you must seek the permission of the lender - or change to a buy-to-let.

Comment: Agree with @SteveMelnikoff , just to add that there may be exceptions if you are considering renting to family members.

Comment: @Vicky: quite right. Typically, BTL mortgages specifically exclude renting to family. For that, you may need a [regulated BTL](http://www.property118.com/what-is-a-regulated-buy-to-let/29139/).

Comment: My relatives who did this (one bought a house and rented it to another family member, for perfectly sensible reasons) were actually able to get a completely normal high street mortgage